# How to use a FragmentDialog in a class that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to display a `Fragment Dialog` when a user clicks on an item on my recycler view.

The bit I am stuck on is how to use a `FragmentDialog` in a class that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`?

This is what I have so far:

```
  public class FinalHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public FinalHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            TextView username= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.username);
            TextView address = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ViewFragmentDialog viewFragmentDialog = new ViewFragmentDialog();
                    viewFragmentDialog.show() // THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE. THE `show` METHOD EXPECTS A FRAGMENTACTIVITY
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The `viewFragmentDialog.show()` method is where I am having some difficulty - because it is expecting `Fragment Activity` but I am using `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

Answer (score 1):

I won't use a `DialogFragment` in this case, if you want explicitly call it from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. The main reason is that you need access to the `FragmentManager`  to `show()` your `DialogFragment`'s subclass, and you don't. I see two possible solution. The easiest one is to use a normal `AlertDialog`. You need a context to access it that you can easily retrieve with `itemView.getContext()`, or use a `Delegate` (aka `Listener`) to communicate with the `Activity`/`Fragment`, and show the `DialogFragment` from there

Comment: What about a normal `Dialog`? How do I add values to it line by line? Any ideas?

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder accepts an adapter. Have a look here [setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to add multiple buttons to the `AlertDialog` such as `Modify`. That wouldn't be `PositiveButton` or `NegativeButton` so what would it be?